# Measurability of a parametrized conditional expectation

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $\mathcal{G}\subset\mathcal{F}$ a Sub-$\sigma$-Algebra. Moreover, let $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a random variable and $F:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a measurable function with

$$\mathbb{E}\big[\;F(X,a)\;\big] \;<\; \infty$$

for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

I am wondering, if we can assume the conditional expectation of $F(X,\;\cdot\;)$, if seen as a function

$$\mathbb{E}\big[\;F(X,\;\cdot\;)\;|\;\mathcal{G}\;\big] \;:\; \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \quad,$$

to be (jointly) $(\mathcal{G}\otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable.

From what I understand so far, for a fixed $a\in\mathbb{R}$, the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}\big[\;F(X,a)\;|\;\mathcal{G}\;\big]$ exists and is a $(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable function.

Your ideas, hints and references are highly appreciated! Thank you.

---

**UPDATE**

In case anybody else stumbles upon this question: there are readily-available results under stronger assumptions on the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}\big[F(X,a)|\mathcal{G}\big]$, namely right-continuity in $a$.

C.f.: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40436/a-question-on-measurability-in-product-spaces)  with reference to Cinlar's Probability and Stochastics, and [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-031-02/S0002-9939-1972-0291403-X/).

In any case, fedja has given the correct answer for the conditions of the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should be careful with how you phrase your question: the conditional expectation is defined up to a set of probability $0$, so you can (almost) always destroy the joint measurability by choosing bad slices. The best we can hope for is that we *can make* it measurable and that is, indeed, the case. Start with the functions of the kind $\chi_{E\times F}$ where $E$ and $F$ are measurable sets in $\Omega$ and $\mathbb R$ respectively. Then extend the result to the corresponding ring (finite unions of pairwise disjoint product sets). Then show that the sets $S\subset \Omega\times \mathbb R$ such that we can choose a jointly measurable conditional expectation for $\chi_S$ form a monotone class. This will give you the whole product $\sigma$-algebra by the monotone class lemma. After that just represent each non-negative function as an increasing limit of simple functions and any function as the difference of two non-negative functions.

Comment: Dear @fedja, thank you for your time and effort. As far as I understand your answer, there will always exist a jointly measurable conditional expectation for a jointly measurable $F$, and you suggest showing this using a construction starting from simple functions? Is this actually a readily available result from the relevant literature?

Comment: @Mark As to the statement, you understand it right. As to the literature, it should be (the chance that you are the first person interested in such stuff is $0.000\dots$) but, alas, answering this question for sure requires a much more knowledgeable person than I.